# Difference between 更好 and 比较好?

Tags: mandarin

I'm confused about the difference between 更好 and 比较好. Since both seem to mean "better", how are these used differently? In what cases would you use them?

Answer (score 12):

Here's my take on it.

`更好` = "*even* better." For example, `X很好。Y更好。= "X is good. Y is even better."` This comparison could be over time too: `X已经很好，现在更好了 = "X was already good, now it's even better."`

`比较好` = "better", without an implication that the object of comparison was/is already good. So, it's acceptable to say `X不怎么样，Y比较好。= "X kind of sucks, Y is better"`

For more example sentences, check out Allset's grammar wiki: [更 geng](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%22Even_more%22_with_%22geng%22) and [比较 bijiao](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22rather%22_with_%22bijiao%22).